# How to detect when Text gets elided

Tags: qt, text, qml, qtquick2

My UI contains a Text field with

```
  horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
  maximumLineCount: 5
  wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
  elide: Text.ElideRight
```

When the text does not fit, the last line should end with "... MORE"  where "MORE" should be focusable. This will probably be a separate Text field where the visibility is controlled by whether or not the text is elided.

But how can I detect when a Text gets elided?

Comment: [`Text.truncated`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#truncated-prop) is true when "..." shows.

Comment: @mcchu Thanks! Apparently, I overlooked it in the docs (feeling pretty embarrassed now) . If you convert it to an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `Text` gets elided, it is [`truncated`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#truncated-prop). Here's a simple example:

```
Text {
    id: longText

    width: 100
    elide: Text.ElideRight
    text: "this is a long long long long string"
}
Text {
    visible: longText.truncated
    anchors.left: longText.right
    text: "More"
}
```