# How can I read listmodel role property in main.qml?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, listmodel

In main.qml, I am updating listModel dynamically on every function addItem() call. Herein, I am setting two role; buttonTypeRole and source. OneText.qml file has a Text field. Actually, after inserting buttonTypeRole and source into listModel, I want to know whether source is being truncated or not.

IS ANY WAY TO READ OneText.qml TEXT TRUNCATED PROPERTY IN main.qml FILE?

main.qml

```
function additem()
{

 listModel.insert(tlist.listModel.count , {"buttonTypeRole":"OneText.qml", "source":editText})
 console.log("model-- "+tlist.listModel.get(sourceIndex).t)
}
```

listModel and ListView snapshot:

```
Item
{
property alias listModel: listModel

ListModel
{
    id:listModel
}

Rectangle
{
    id:listHolder
    border.color: "transparent"
    border.width: 3
    color:"transparent"
    height:560
    width:600
    focus:true

    ListView
    {
        //id:listview
        x:5
        y:5
        spacing:10
        width:700
        height:listHolder.height - 20
        id:list
        boundsBehavior: ListView.StopAtBounds
        model:listModel
        delegate:listComponent
        clip: true
        snapMode:ListView.SnapToItem
    }
}
Component   
{
    id:listComponent
    Rectangle
    {
        //color:"grey"
        width:obj.width
        height:obj.height
        border.color: "red"
        Loader
        {
            id:itemDisplay
            source:buttonTypeRole

        }
    }
}
}
```

buttonTypeRole :OneText.qml snapshot

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
Item
{
id:one
height:obj.height
width:obj.width
Text
{
    id:textOne
    height:obj.height
    width:obj.width
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    verticalAlignment: "AlignVCenter"
    anchors.leftMargin: 10
    font.family: obj.fontFamily
    font.bold: obj.fontBoldStyle == "true" ? true : false
    font.pixelSize: obj.fontSize
    text:source
    elide: Text.ElideRight
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Can you elaborate why you need this info? There might be a different approach to your use-case

Comment: I have a xml file(list of strings) & a data.jason file that contains properties information(widht/height/font/size) about each string. I read .xml file using xmlListModel and showing list (say listview id:xmlList), & have added a button name VALIDATE on each item. data.jason has parsed in cpp file and created a map for each string. Upon VALIDATE button press, I send xmlList item text to cpp &get width/height/font/size properties in qml and draw a label to see if text if fitting within fetched width and height or not. If it truncates,I need to remove that list item from xmlList.

Comment: I think you should have a look at [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html). This enables you to measure a text completely from C++

Comment: What do you mean by "truncated" ? Do you mean that you want to check if the text is using ellipses? You can call `textOne.truncated` to check if this has occurred. This previous question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019822/how-to-detect-when-text-gets-elided