# Detect when a text is elided

Tags: qt, qstring

There is already [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019822/how-to-detect-when-text-gets-elided) that covers my question, but it is specific to QML. I am asking the question for C++ code.

Here is my code sample :

```
QFontMetrics boldMetrics(boldFont);
auto elidedName = boldMetrics.elidedText(nameToElide, Qt::ElideMiddle, (ui->lDescription->width() - (textBoundingRect - NameBoundingRect - 1)));
```

The elidedText is as expected, but I need now to detect if it has been elided to perform additional processing. Of course, I can always check if the elidedName contains "..." but I am looking for an efficient way to do the check.
I expected either the `elidedText()` to provide an optional out parameter or an overloaded version that would output this information, but apparently this is not the case.
`QString` and `QFontMetrics` apparently don't keep that information either.

Do someone know if there is a way to have the information about if the elision really took place without having to do an inefficient string check?

Comment: Maybe you could call `boldMetrics.horizontalAdvance(nameToElide)` and compare the result to the available width, to check if your text will be elided

Comment: From the documentation, it doesn't seem that horizontalAdvance() returns the width of the whole string.

Comment: But even if it is the case, this is still an indirect way of getting the information. Same as looking for a specific char in the name to elide to check if it was elided.